# Convert Visual Format Language greater than to Constraint

Tags: swift, autolayout, visual-format-language

How would I convert this into a constraint?

```
"V:|->=0-[contentView]->=0-|"
```

Would it look like this?

```
contentView.topAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified which view is the `superview` of `contentView`, we'll have to use `contentView.superview!` for the containing view.  Therefore, your visual format is equivalent to:

```
contentView.topAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.superview!.topAnchor, constant: 0.0)
contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.superview!.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
```

**Notes:**

1. If `contentView` has already been added as a subview of another view (which you should always do before creating constraints), then force unwrapping `contentView.superview` is safe.
2. `contentView` will start lower on the screen than its `superview` and the coordinates grow in the downward direction, so its offset will be larger making the constraint `greaterThanOrEqualTo` the superview's `topAnchor`.
3. Likewise, `contentView` will end above or touching its superview's `bottomAnchor`, so the `constant` in this case will be `lessThanOrEqualTo` `0`.